# selenium stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have an e-commerce page and there are multiple products on a page. I need to click the link of a product then return on the main page and click the link of the next product, but when I return, the elements can't be found anymore.

```
Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get("https://www.emag.ro/")

search_bar = driver.find_element_by_id("searchboxTrigger") 
search_bar.send_keys("laptopuri")
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

main = None

try:
    main = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "main-container"))
    )
    print("Page loaded,main retrived succesfully")
    print(" ")

except:
    driver.quit()

products = main.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")

for product in products:
    raw_name = product.text

    raw_price = product.find_element_by_css_selector("p.product-new-price").text

    link = product.find_element_by_tag_name("a")

    #clicking the link
    link.click()

    spec_page = None
    try:
        spec_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-12"))
        )
    except:
        driver.quit()

    print(spec_page)
  
    driver.back()
```

After the first iteration, I get the following error :
`selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document` on line `raw_name = product.text`,basically at the beginning of the loop.
I assume the page is not loading properly or something like that, I tried using time.sleep before going through the loop but nothing

Comment: Is it ok to use `requests`/`beautifulsoup` modules?

Comment: As you already know all of the links from the first time you go to the homepage, why not just store them all and then iterate through each link rather than navigating back and forth?

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing `driver.back()`, it will go back to previous page and by the time it will reach to original page all the defined elements will become stale. You need to redefined them like below :-

This should handle the exception.

```
products = len(main.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data"))

j = 0
for product in range(products):
    elements = main.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item.js-product-data")
    raw_name = elements[j].text

    raw_price = elements[j].find_element_by_css_selector("p.product-new-price").text

    link = elements[j].find_element_by_tag_name("a")

    # clicking the link
    link.click()

    spec_page = None
    try:
        spec_page = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "col-md-12"))
        )
    except:
        driver.quit()

    print(spec_page)
    j = j + 1
    driver.back()
```